# Can't register portlets on Liferay

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, liferay, portlet

I'm using liferay 6.2 and i'm trying do deploy my project in a tomcat 7 application server. The problem is that i can't deploy the project portlets and the only related messages are these:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
7/Jan/2015 17:33:54 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet.xml
7/Jan/2015 17:33:54 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
WARNING: A docBase C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
7/Jan/2015 17:33:54 org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet' did not find a matching property.
7/Jan/2015 17:33:57 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
```

I've already tried everything: deleted the inside of temp and work folder and the project xml inside the conf folder, restarded and cleaned the server but the portlets aren't registered anyway. Sometimes after doing these actions i get another messages from the console:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet
17:55:28,834 INFO [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:204] Processing BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet.xml
17:55:28,857 INFO [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][PortletExplodedTomcatListener:61] Modifying portlets for C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\deploy\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet.xml
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet\WEB-INF\classes
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet\WEB-INF\classes
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet\WEB-INF\jsp
7/Jan/2015 17:55:29 org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui is already defined
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
17:55:30,371 INFO [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseDeployer:2383] Modifying Servlet 3.0 C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet\WEB-INF\web.xml
17:55:30,372 INFO [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][PortletExplodedTomcatListener:67] Portlets for C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\deploy\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet.xml modified successfully
17:55:30,373 INFO [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseExplodedTomcatListener:49] Copying file C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\deploy\BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet.xml to C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost
7/Jan/2015 17:55:40 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet]
7/Jan/2015 17:55:40 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet] has started
7/Jan/2015 17:55:42 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/BankingCardsManagementToolLiferay-portlet] is completed
```

But the portlets continue unregistered.
What is happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are copying the WAR files in the `C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\` directory instead of the `C:\Users\dpinheiro\Desktop\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\deploy\` directory.

Liferay hot-deploys the WAR file from the `/deploy` directory.

Oh and one question, what do you mean by this: `... and the project xml inside the conf folder ...`

Hope this helps.

Comment: What i meant was the xml files inside the "liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost" folder. I don't have the problem anymore but i couldn't find the reason :( Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One of my subordinate also faced same problem.But he is using eclipse so i just enabled "show console when standard out changes" and "show console when standard error changes". Now he able to see the registered messages in console.Please see the attached image to enable those configurations for eclipse console[image: Image to enable eclipse configurations for console]